# Projects wont run on Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

I made a simple project on NetBeans 8.2 and for some reason, It won run my project. The symbol for the run button is unclickable.

I've clicked the run on the menu bar but it's still not working for me.

```
public class FirstFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    } 

}
```

//I tried using this command on my project. Just to test.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Is your filename the same as the class name? (the file should be called FirstFile.java)

Comment: yes, the file name is FirstFile.java and the problem Im having is that my run button is   unclickable.

Answer (score 2):

> Right click on the file-->Run File

Answer (score 0):

Another project might be already running in your NetBeans,
[image]

Click the button below to stop the execution of the current project and then try to run your programme. Or else you can close NetBeans and reopen it and then run your programme.